# Drawing a double line using itext PDF

Tags: java, pdf-generation, itext

I am using itext to write the content to the PDF.

I want to draw a double line as below.

=================================================================================

I have used the lineseparator method twice. but it draws the lines with more gap.

I want to draw the lines with some less space between those two.

Can any body help me on this asap.

Comment: It will be difficult to answer your question without a valid code sample. Please post your code, preferably as an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) that demonstrates your problem.

Answer (score 4):

You can adjust the spaces between the 2 `LineSeparator` added by setting the offset of the second seperator:

Something like;

```
document.add(new LineSeparator());
LineSeparator sep = new LineSeparator();
sep.setOffset(5);
document.add(sep);
```

**Output:**

[image]

Adjust the separator offset with the value that suits your need.

Comment: Thanks for giving the answer. It was working good when adding to the document. I want to draw a double line border to the bottom of the cell .How could we use this in the cell of PdfPTable. Can you please let me know this

Comment: @Srinivas B I'd suggest opening a separate question with your relevant code, that would help to zero in on the issue quicker!

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the setLeading() method in com.itextpdf.text.Phrase

Comment: I want to draw a double line border to the bottom of the cell. how can I acheive this ?